# Print tekst based on form information in php

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm very new to coding, total noob, and I'm trying to print out a text based on grades. Like if they choose 1, then print "Bad", etc. 
I'm thinking I could use if/else, but I'm so new to coding I don't know. I've been googling, but I just dont know who to get the form and the text to work together. Can anyone help please?

```
    <section class="evaluation">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>More info here</p>
    <p>Gve this a grade [1-6]</p>
    <form action="evaluation.php" method="post">
      <select class="evalSelect">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
      </select>
      <input class="evalButton" type="submit" name="name" value="Give grade">
    </form>
  </section>
```

I'f I can use something like this, how can I get it to work togehter with the form above?

```
     switch ($grade) {
        case "1":
        echo "Bad";
     break;
        case "2":
        echo "Not so bad";
    break;
        case "3":
        echo "Better";
    break;
        case "4":
        echo "Even better";
    break;
        case "5":
    echo "Good";
    break;
        case "6":
    echo "Very good";
    break;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to add the value property to each option tag with a value. Then in PHP you can check wether evalSelect was set or not and what it contained.

Edit your form to:

```
   <section class="evaluation">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>More info here</p>
    <p>Gve this a grade [1-6]</p>
    <form action="evaluation.php" method="post">
      <select class="evalSelect">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
      </select>
      <input class="evalButton" type="submit" name="name" value="Give grade">
    </form>
  </section>
```

And for the PHP this should work:

```
// evaluation.php
if (isset($_POST['evalSelect']))
{
    $grade = $_POST['evalSelect'];
    switch ($grade) {
        case "1":
            echo "Bad";
            break;
        case "2":
            echo "Not so bad";
            break;
        case "3":
            echo "Better";
            break;
        case "4":
            echo "Even better";
            break;
        case "5":
            echo "Good";
            break;
        case "6":
            echo "Very good";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to echo your text:

```
<section class="evaluation">
<h2>Test</h2>
<p>More info here</p>
<p>Gve this a grade [1-6]</p>
<form action="evaluation.php" method="post">
  <select class="evalSelect" name="evalSelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
  </select>
  <input class="evalButton" type="submit" name="name" value="Give grade">
</form>
</section>
```

And in `evaluation.php` do something like:

```
$grade = $_POST['evalSelect'];

switch ($grade) {
   case "1":
   echo "Bad";
break;
   case "2":
   echo "Not so bad";
break;
   case "3":
   echo "Better";
break;
   case "4":
   echo "Even better";
break;
   case "5":
echo "Good";
break;
   case "6":
   echo "Very good";
break;
}
```